Between pagination and sort function integration error in Angular
When i click pagination my function is sorting constantly but i dont want to do this. The same problem applies when I want to change "rows"
I tried remove this codes =>   const sort: string = this.getFirstRecord();
this.getPagedCategory("", currentPage, this.rows, sort); and this codes => const sort: string = this.getFirstRecord();
this.getPagedCategory("", currentPage, this.rows, sort); but it didn't work.
